# Battery percentage is not visible on top bar of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for Surface Pro (Surface_Pro_1796)

Tags: 20.04, power-management, gnome-shell, battery, acpi

I have done a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Surface Pro (Surface_Pro_1796) and it seems like there is some issue with battery percentage which supposed to be displayed on top bar of GNOME desktop. Did some research on this and tried the following without any success:

1. I have no entry for battery under these directories `/proc/acpi/battery` or `/sys/class/power_supply`

   `/proc/acpi/battery`:
   [image: /proc/acpi/battery]

   `/sys/class/power_supply`:
   [image: /sys/class/power_supply]
2. Ran `acpi -b` command - no output.
3. Installed **GNOME Tweaks** and tried to enable batter percentage but it didn't help.

   [image: GNOME Tweaks]
4. Installed Linux Surface kernel from [this](https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface) link, but it didn't help. Although it should not help, but gave a try.

I am not sure what else to try, please help.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead copy & paste the text here and use [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Comment: Finally after doing lot of research and experiments I was able to solve this issue, check this for more info : https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface/issues/666

Answer (score 0):

Here are the commands I ran in sequence to install linux surface kernel:

```
wget -qO - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/master/pkg/keys/surface.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian release main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linux-surface.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-surface linux-image-surface linux-libc-dev-surface surface-ipts-firmware libwacom-surface
sudo apt-get install linux-surface-secureboot-mok
export GRUB_CONFIG=`sudo find /boot -name "grub.cfg"`
sudo update-grub
sudo grep 'menuentry ' $GRUB_CONFIG | cut -f 2 -d "'" | nl -v 0
sudo grub-reboot 1
sudo reboot
```

Reference: https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface/issues/666