# I am having problems with displaying battery percentage

Tags: battery

I recently switched my surface pro 7 to Ubuntu. Everything was going fine until I realized that it is not displaying my battery percentage, I don't know where if at all I can find it. I tried setting things up like Gnome Tweaks and it can't even find my battery. Any and all help would be appreciated, I really want to make this work.

Comment: checked and worked: do this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310636/ubuntu-20-04-cannot-detect-the-battery-in-surface-pro-6-laptop and this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1373939/error-401-unauthorized-with-apt-install-on-surface-book-2

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal, try:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface show-battery-percentage true`

Comment: I tried that, no errors or anything, but nothing changed. After I tried restarting it, and still nothing changed.

Comment: @DerrkTheJerk Do you even have a battery icon showing?

Comment: It shows no batter icon, no.

Comment: @DerrkTheJerk you can try `apt-get install indicator-power` ....though I am skeptical it will actually work... I think the problem is that it is a surface pro...

Comment: Same thing, tried it, rebooted, nothing. I am beginning to agree with that statement. Hopefully there is something I can do.

Comment: @DerrkTheJerk Don't take my word as gospel, I just searched real quick and this is the first i am seeing of it, but it looks like there is a special kernel? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257997/battery-percentage-is-not-visible-on-top-bar-of-ubuntu-20-04-lts-for-surface-pro There are some links on that page... https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface

Comment: I am trying those steps, but on command number four it is kicking back `E: Unable to locate package linux-libc-dev-surface`.

Comment: I followed the steps 0 through 3 (as it said four was optional if I wanted a fancy kernel). Nothing seemed to change even after reboot. No errors or anything, just nothing happened, other than the outputs. I honestly don't really know what I am doing, I don't already know linux, I was trying to learn it this way.

Comment: I tried to boot from the 5.1.15 kernal I had just setup and it said `error: /boot/vmlinuz-5.1.15-surface-linux-surface has invalid signature.` and `error: you need to load the kernel first`.

Comment: I dont know enough about it to advise beyond what's actually in the instructions... I removed that other comment because I just noticed you have a surface pro 7... That's not on the list of "supported devices". I don't know if that actually implies anything. As far as your last comment, according to this, it says secureboot is your problem... https://www.reddit.com/r/SurfaceLinux/comments/cdc4bl/trouble_after_installing_jakedays_kernal_beginner/ ...again, I am only looking up the error messages you are presenting.