# Ubuntu 20.04 cannot detect the battery in Surface pro 6 laptop

Tags: 20.04, battery, surface

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 (kernel 5.10) on my surface pro 6. Everything works with no issue except the Battery status/percentage is not detected (I already have played with the 'tweaks' battery percentage key). Also when I run "acpi -a", I get this "Adapter 0: off-line". Any idea what is missing?

Comment: I wonder, does the camera work?

Comment: Nope. Actually I have covered the cam with tape, so I don't think I would need it ... :D

Answer (score 0):

According to the linux-surface project's [feature Matrix](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Supported-Devices-and-Features#feature-matrix), the battery status works after installing the surface kernel.

Follow these steps to install this special kernel (I found these steps on this [page](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup#Debian--Ubuntu). Please refer to that page for more details. If you encounter an issue, you can report it in the GitHub issues).

First you need to import the keys.

```
$ wget -qO - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/master/pkg/keys/surface.asc \
    | gpg --dearmor | sudo dd of=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/linux-surface.gpg
```

Now add the repository configuration

```
$ echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian release main" \
    | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linux-surface.list
```

Now update APT.

```
$ sudo apt update
```

Now you can install the linux-surface kernel and its dependencies. You should also enable the iptsd service for touchscreen support.

```
$ sudo apt install linux-image-surface linux-headers-surface iptsd libwacom-surface
```

```
$ sudo systemctl enable iptsd
```

After that you can install the secureboot key of the `linux-surface` team.

```
$ sudo apt install linux-surface-secureboot-mok
```

The linux-surface kernel will be installed alongside the default kernel provided by the distribution. This way you have a backup kernel you can use if something goes wrong. The bootloader will pick up the kernel by default, but you should update its configuration to make sure it was recognized.

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

Finally, reboot your system and you should boot into the linux-surface kernel.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems the the "linux-surface kernel" is a different/extended version of a standard Linux kernel. I believe their only difference is that the Surface one has additional drivers and some other minor differences. Because of security measures, I don't trust this Surface kernel same as the Standard Linux kernel and I should exactly know what they have added to a standard kernel to create the new one. I may go over their drivers and compile it or my kernel and see if I can make it work.

Comment: @AshkSam A lot of people use this project's kernel (look at the number of stars in GitHub). I doubt that it has any malicious code. But of course, it is upto you. I am not affiliated with this project, though.